# Box auto silding fromleft to right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three boxes and now, there are working as i expected. But, I need this work automatically every 30 secs without 'click' event. Please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ykbgT/8493/. Any idea?

code as below

```
<div id="box1" class="box">Div #1</div>
<div id="box2" class="box">Div #2</div>
<div id="box3" class="box">Div #3</div>

$('.box').click(function () {
    $('.box').each(function () {
        if ($(this).offset().left < 0) {
            $(this).css("left", "150%");
        } else if ($(this).offset().left > $('.box').width()) {
            $(this).animate({
                left: '50%',
            }, 500);
        } else {
            $(this).animate({
                left: '-150%',
            }, 500);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: In future, when you ask a question, please include *all* the relevant code in your question; leaving the JavaScript in an external site when you're asking a JavaScript question is ridiculous, and unhelpful. Help us to help you, and then you get better answers (usually) more quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a javascript method called setinterval();

> setInterval() - executes a function, over and over again, at specified
>   time intervals.

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dowomentfart/ykbgT/8496/)**

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('.box').each(function() {
        if ($(this).offset().left < 0) {
            $(this).css("left", "150%");
        } else if ($(this).offset().left > $('.box').width()) {
            $(this).animate({
                left: '50%',
            }, 500 );
        } else {
            $(this).animate({
                left: '-150%',
            }, 500 );
        }
    });
}, 30000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('.box').each(function() {
        if ($(this).offset().left < 0) {
            $(this).css("left", "150%");
        } else if ($(this).offset().left > $('.box').width()) {
            $(this).animate({
                left: '50%',
            }, 500);
        } else {
            $(this).animate({
                left: '-150%',
            }, 500);
        }
    });
}, 30000);
```